# I need to create a search bar on sales order view page in customer login magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, orders, filter, search, sales

I need to search and filter the orders in sales order page customer side as like admin side also need the search box. But i can't find any related documentations or solutions. whether this can do in this page magento 2.3

Result to be :
[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

yes,
you can override **vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml** in your theme or module
and add your custom form there

Comment: But there is no form it only the page rendering template

Comment: you need to create a form in overridden template